# Syntax Error While Trying to Exit a ForLoop Using Def

Tags: python

I am trying to return a list of random floating numbers using only `random.random` for library function. I keep getting a syntax error whenever I try and close my block. Here is my code:

```
def randomFloats(n, lower, upper) :
...     for i in range(n) : 
...             return [random.random()*(upper-lower)]
                break
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Post the whole error message.

Comment: what is the output that you are expecting ?

Comment: Any code below and on the same level than `return` will never be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code. Let's break these down:

### Use of `break`

The Python statement `break` is intended for exiting a loop during its run. An example of this would be:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i == 2:
        break
    else:
        print(i)
```

The output would then be:

```
0
1
```

Perhaps from this you can already tell that the use of `break` in your code is not proper.

### Use of `return`

The return statement is the 'final' execution of a function; or in other words, when the `return` statement is reached, the function returns, and exits. An example to showcase this:

```py
def func():
    for i in range(10):
        return i
        print("IN HERE!")

print(func())
```

Outputs:

```
0
```

As you can see, the function does not return 0-10 as perhaps you thought it would. You should also note that "IN HERE" was **not** printed, as we exited the function.

### Fixing your code

Now looking at your code with the knowledge we have above, we can see some obvious mistakes:

- You have a break statement that is never reached.
- You have a return statement inside the for-loop that exits the function before the execution of the for-loop is done.
- Thus, you are not generating multiple random numbers. You are generating one number.

### "Syntax" error

This is an assumption of mine: you are mistaking the `break` statement as the functions' closing statement. The reality is that Python does not have `end` statements like other languages, and instead, the end statement is the indentation. Instead of writing 'break' in the interpreter, try simply running your function without it and making sure to press enter to exit out of the function declaration (you will no longer see dots, and instead `>>>`).

[image: Press enter.]

### Solution

Perhaps the code you are looking for (without list-comprehension) is the following:

```py
import random

def randomFloats(n, lower, upper):
    l = [] # Creating a list named 'l'
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(random.random() * (upper - lower)) # Appending n random numbers to list l.

    return l # Returning the list l.

print(randomFloats(10, 1, 10))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Felipe that was very helpful and you have resolved my issue, specifically with your syntax error section.

Comment: Glad to be of help -- I figured that was your issue based on the clues you gave.

Answer (score 1):

That code will indeed go into a loop (assuming the indentation is consistent) but, on the first iteration of that loop, it will return a list containing a *single* random float value.

If you want to return a *list* of more random values, you should use:

```
import random
def randomFloats(n, lower, upper) :
    return [random.random()*(upper-lower) for _ in range(n)]
```